# Need update table attrans

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table `attrans`

```
[Card_ID],
[date_att],
[time_att],
[Transaction_type],
[Processed],
[Shift_No],
[Shift_Type],
[Instead],
[user_id],
[tran_id]
```

`transaction_type` means `(1 in 2 out)`

The employee transaction in this table and may employee get `in 21-1-2016 20:30 out 23-01-2016 8:30`

I need to update this table to make all user get out `20:30` if it get `in 8:30 and 8:30 if get in 20:30`

And make in transaction for get in `8:30` or `20:30` depending on out time

Comment: What's the part you find difficult?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution by join technique:

```
;with Attrans as
(
  select cast(1 as int) as [user_id], cast(1 as int) as transaction_type,
    cast('2015-12-31' as date) as date_att, cast('8:30' as time) as time_att
  union all
  select 1, 2, '2015-12-31', '16:00'
  union all
  select 1, 1, '2016-01-01', '20:30'
  union all
  select 1, 2, '2016-01-02', '10:30'
)
select
  a_in.*,
  a_out.date_att as date_out,
  cast(case when a_out.date_att = a_in.date_att then '20:30' else '8:30' end as time) as time_out
from Attrans a_in
inner join Attrans a_out on a_out.user_id = a_in.user_id 
  and (a_out.date_att = a_in.date_att and a_in.time_att = '8:30'
    or a_out.date_att = dateadd(dd, 1, a_in.date_att) and a_in.time_att = '20:30')
where a_in.transaction_type = 1 and a_out.transaction_type = 2
order by a_in.date_att
```

of course, if the real task is more complicated (e.g. to collapse multiple rows generated per day for a user) you will need some other approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit challenging to understand what exactly you want, since there is no StartTime and EndTime (and I have some experience with time clocking systems). I can suggest you UPDATE wit CASE approach. If you provide more information I can help you to adjust it for you case. Is [time_att] is a time record? It seems to be [time attended] field

```
UPDATE
        [attrans]
    SET
        [EndTime] =
        (
            CASE [EndTime]
                WHEN '08:30' THEN '20:30' 
                WHEN '20:30' THEN '08:30'
            ELSE
                -- do nothing
            END
        )

        ,[StartTime] = 
        (
            CASE [EndTime]
                WHEN '20:30' THEN '08:30'
                WHEN '08:30' THEN '20:30'
            ELSE
              -- do nothing
            END
        )
```